# Area of Polygon - C++

Tags: c++, geometry

I'm trying to write a code to calculate the area of a polygon, but it looks like something isn't adding up. Might be that the formula is off, or I need to use the absolute value function?

```
double polygon_area(int actual_size, double x[], double y[])
{

    printf("In polygon.area\n");                //Initial basic test

    int i;
    double area;

    area = 0.0;

    for (i = 0; i <= max_size; i = i + 1)
    {

        area = (x[i + 1] + x[i]) * (y[i + 1] - y[i]);

        area = (area * 0.50);

    }

    printf("The area of the polygon is %lf  \n", area);

    return (area);
}
```

Comment: Take a look here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html

Comment: area += (x[i + 1] + x[i]) * (y[i + 1] - y[i]);

Comment: What is `max_size`? What if `max_size` is larger than the length of either `x` or `y`? Do you mean to use `actual_size` instead of `max_size`?

Comment: I defined max_size to 20 earlier in the code!

Comment: @Yuliya : sorry, my point is that if you have fewer than `maxsize` items in the `x` and `y` arrays, then you could be using unexpected/unitialised values in the area calculation that could contribute to an incorrect result. [R Sahu's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28534437/21945) explains this and other issues in detail.

Answer (score 5):

Problems that I see:

1. You are computing the area as if there are `max_size` elements to compute the area from. I think you need to use `actual_size`.
2. Since C++ indices for arrays start with `0`, they need to stop at `actual_size-1`, not `actual_size`. Instead of

   ```
   for (i = 0; i <= max_size; i = i + 1)
   ```

   use

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < actual_size; ++i)
   // Using ++i is more idiomatic that using i = i + 1
   ```
3. Computation of area is wrong. Replace the lines:

   ```
   area = (x[i + 1] + x[i]) * (y[i + 1] - y[i]);

   area = (area * 0.50);
   ```

   by

   ```
   area += 0.5*(the area term);
   ```
4. Calculation of the area term needs to use wrap around indices. Say you have 5 points. When processing the 5-th point, you have to use indices `4` and `0`, not `4` and `5`.

   Instead of

   ```
   x[i + 1] + x[i]) * (y[i + 1] - y[i]);
   ```

   use

   ```
   x[(i + 1)%actual_size] + x[i]) * (y[(i + 1)%actual_size] - y[i]);
   ```
5. The computation for the area term needs to be fixed. Instead of using

   ```
   0.5*(x2 + x1) * (y2 - y1))
   ```

   you need to use:

   ```
   0.5*(x1.y2 - x2.y1)
   ```

Here's a simplified version of the function:

```
double polygon_area(int actual_size, double x[], double y[])
{
    printf("In polygon.area\n");

    double area = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < actual_size; ++i)
    {
       int j = (i + 1)%actual_size;
       area += 0.5 * (x[i]*y[j] -  x[j]*y[i]);
    }

    printf("The area of the polygon is %lf  \n", area);

    return (area);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So I added what you suggested, %actual_size, but that gives me a continuous number, way up in the zillions. Not sure if that was supposed to happen.

Comment: @YuliyaBaranovskaya, not sure why you would get that. BTW, I updated my answer with the correct formula to compute area of a polygon.